# How can I get all CREATE VIEW statements in Teradata?

Tags: metadata, teradata

How to get all CREATE VIEW statements with a single query?

This Query is used to get the definition of a single view:

```
show view db.tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the catalog views (h/t to [Dieter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/66829/dnoeth) for alerting me to truncation of `RequestText` in `TablesV`):

```
SELECT
  Tbl.DatabaseName
 ,Tbl.TableName
 ,COALESCE(TblText.LineNo,1) AS LineNo
 ,COALESCE(TblText.RequestText,Tbl.RequestText) AS RequestText
FROM
  DBC.TablesV Tbl
LEFT JOIN
  DBC.TableTextV TblText
    ON TblText.DatabaseName = Tbl.DatabaseName
            AND TblText.TableName = Tbl.TableName
        AND TblText.TableKind = Tbl.TableKind
WHERE
  DatabaseName = <Database name>
    AND TableKind = 'V'
```

Comment: Request Text will have the DDL truncated when it's too large. `RequestTxtOverflow` will indicate this and then the full code can be found in `DBC.TableTextV`